# Looking for suitable mudguard, based on tyre size

Tags: fenders

Will my bike (tyre size 700 x 23) be suitable tobe fitted with this mudguards (universal 28” & 26”)???

Thanks all.

[image]

Comment: What type of bike do you have. 700cx23 tire suggests a road bike. Depending on the road bike you might not have much clearance for fenders. The fenders are 40 mm wide, which is likely too wide for most road bikes, unless the frame can clear 32-35 mm tires.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

A 700c rim with a 23"mm tire is under 28" in diameter. The max tire width is specified at 40mm.

The "28inch" spec is a bit confusing as it's not a common wheel size (700c, 29" etc). I'm guessing a 700c rim with a 40mm tire is about 28" in diameter.

Comment: 28" is a fairly common (mis)translation of 700c in some European countries that should know better than to use inches.